# Overriding and inheritance in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm working with CSS and Bootstrap and I'm new to all that.

I actually want to integrate two different types of carousels in my web page.
Knowing that bootstrap has a carousel class defined (in the bootstrap.min.css stylesheet), I have created a custom stylesheet named custom.css that I've linked in my html code (as well as the bootstrap.min.css, of course) and which contains another styling for the bootstrap carousel class to customize the first carousel of my web page. Now, I want to customize the second carousel of my web page: I don't know how to proceed. If I create another custom stylesheet file in which I'll customize the second carousel and then integrate it in my html code (using the  tag), there will be some kind of conflict. I'm pretty confused...

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can give each carousel their own ID, and style it like that:

```
<div id="first-carousel" class="carousel"></div>
<div id="second-carousel" class="carousel"></div>

#first-carousel elementToStyle {
    // css here
}

#second-carousel elementToStyle {
    // css here
}
```

Where the elementToStyle can be any of bootstrap's carousel class names or elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!